# How to complete `..` to `../` in eshell

Tags: completion, eshell

A BASH completes `..` to `../` when pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>, that is, it just adds a forward slash. Tiny as it might seem, I'm so used to this behaviour that I desperately miss it in eshell. Is there a way to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eshell` needs some context to know how to complete, so the following example assumes we have some context like typing `cd ..` and then the tab key.

The default value for `eshell-cmpl-dir-ignore` is:

```
"\\`\\(\\.\\.?\\|CVS\\)/\\'"
```

The variable `pcomplete-dir-ignore` is made buffer-local by `eshell` and set to the value of `eshell-cmpl-dir-ignore`.  [See the function `eshell-cmpl-initialize`.]

*Prior* to opening up an `eshell` buffer, evaluate:

```
(setq eshell-cmpl-dir-ignore "\\`\\(CVS\\)/\\'")
```

Or, *after* opening an `eshell` buffer, in the active buffer evaluate:

```
(setq pcomplete-dir-ignore "\\`\\(CVS\\)/\\'")
```

Or, simply put the previous example setting the value of `eshell-cmpl-dir-ignore` in your `.emacs` or `init.el` file and restart Emacs.

Comment: Your code does the job when using `eshell-pcomplete` for completion. But I forgot to say that I've bound `<tab>` to `completion-at-point`. Do you happen to also know how to achieve it with `completion-at-point`?

Comment: Nowadays, Eshell's `completion-at-point` also uses pcomplete, so it should work just as well for you.

Comment: @Stefan is correct:  `(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key eshell-mode-map [tab] 'completion-at-point))) (setq eshell-cmpl-dir-ignore "\\`\\(CVS\\)/\\'")` will have the same result -- tested with Emacs 25.

Comment: @Stefan @lawlist It works with `emacs -q`, but not with my configuration. I'm using `helm-mode-completion-at-point` and for some reason `../` doesn't appear in the selection buffer. So I've decided to use `company` for this (which shows `../` as first selection with your code). Works ok.